# Finding a path using multi-dimensional arrays in js

Tags: javascript, math, multidimensional-array, logic, coordinates

I have an x-y grid stored in a multi-dimensional array.  Each point in the x-y grid has a value.

Example:

```
var xy = [
    [0,3,1,1,0],
    [0,0,2,2,1],
    [0,0,1,1,0]
];
```

Assuming the layout of var xy is like an x-y grid (x 1 and y 2 would be 3 for example.

Here's a larger 'print-out' of such a variable, with greater height and width:

```
   (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7) (8) (9) (10) (11) (12) (13)
(1) 0   0   0   1   1   1   2   2   1    1    0    0    0
(2) 0   0   1   1   1   2   2   3   2    2    1    0    0
(3) 0   0   0   1   2   2   3   3   2    1    0    0    0
(4) 0   4   0   1   1   1   2   2   1    0    0    0    8
(5) 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0    0    0    0    4
(6) 0   0   0   0   9   9   9   0   0    0    0    0    0 
(7) 0   0   0   0   9   9   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
```

Now, for the sake of example, pretend that the above layout were a map, like a chessboard.  For starters, to pay no attention to the VALUES of each point on the grid, let's say we want to know which squares a 'game piece' could reach from, say, x4 y8....we could do something like this in js:

```
 var n = ,//total # of items in grid
    a = ,//a certain point on the grid
    r = 5; //range of movement
 for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){ //this would be a double for or something similar to go through the grid properly, but let's pretend i is a given point on the grid.
    Math.abs(((a.xLocation + a.yLocation) - (i.xLocation + i.yLocation)) <= r) //if the positive difference between the current point in the loop and the location of the certain point is less than or equal to the range....true!
 }
```

So in the rough example above a thing at point A can move 5 steps, diagonally, vertically, horizontally, whatever.  We don't know the direction, just the potential for movement.

That's pretty easy to figure out.  The part I'm still trying to get my head around is this: How do you know whether a thing at point a can reach point i based on the VALUES of the grid.  0 means no augmentation, but 1 or 2 takes 1 or 2 or whatever EXTRA the movement to get to.....how do you figure that out for EACH point on the map?  Again, no knowing which direction or path - whether it will be optimal or not.

CLARIFICATION: Imagine a chessboard.  Each square chessboard has a value that represents how many EXTRA movement points it takes to get there.  A given piece, not at all using chess rules, can move, let's say, 5 'movement points' in any direction.  Many squares have a value of 0, thus it requires no further expenditure of movement points.  But a square of 1 would require 2 total movement points, 2 would require 3 total, etc.  Really, you could just as easily add 1 to all the squares below to find out whether a piece in a neighboring square could move there.  However you like.  I'm just looking for some kind of forumula or suggestion that can derive an answer.  Here, look at this much simpler example.

```
    (1) (2) (3)
(1)  0   1   3
(2)  1   X   2
(3)  2   0   1
```

Think of it like a game, where each square represents some kind of terrain disadvantage. Some paths are easier than others, but others are more direct.  You can take any path to get to a certain square, but before the move, which squares are legal and which are not?  So our piece is on X2 Y2, right?  He has 5 movement points.  He wants to know which ones he can move to.  Well, he can move to any of them.  But X1Y1 will cost 1 movement point, X1Y2 will cost 2, X1Y3 will cost 4, etc etc etc.  Easy to figure out.  but if the board is larger, and each potential (unknown) movement takes points, which squares can he move to and which can't he?  Does this make sense?

EDIT 2: A slightly more complex example:

```
    (1) (2) (3) (4) (5)
(1)  0   1   3   0   0
(2)  1   X   2   1   0
(3)  2   0   1   0   0
(4)  1   0   0   1   3
(5)  0   0   0   0   4
```

So our piece in this example is in X2Y2 again, but he wants to know, for each square, if he can make it there - boolean, yes or no.  It's easy with just nine squares, but as the grid grows, so does the complexity.  I can do it manually of course - can he reach X4Y4?  Yes.  But programmatically, how do I get this?

EDIT3: The size of the grid is meaningless, I just realized.  It's really the size of the range.  E.g., if the range of movement is 5, I just need to figure out the viability of squares five squares out in each direction.  So that simplifies it a bit.

EDIT4: I think I have a little better of an idea.  Look at the outermost ring 5 out.  Is it greater than 0?  Then no.  Next outermost ring (4 out).  Greater than 1?  No.  Next outermost ring.  Greater than 2?  Then no.  Etc.  Will that work or could that lead to incorrect results?

Answers (or even just leads in the right direction) in js or jQuery preferred, but even if you can kind of work through the logic, I can translate that into js or jquery.

Comment: Not at all clear how your augmentation works. From reading this I think it means when range of movement r=5, where value of grid is v then actual movement am = r*v, so if v=0 am=0, if v=2 am=10 etc. Is this anywhere close?

Comment: Not really.  I will try to clarify what I'm actually trying to do in the text above.  one moment!  Thanks

Comment: I saw what tripped you up.  I said 1 or 2 times - I meant 1 or 2 extra (which (x1) is times, but still...ambiguious.  Changed the language a bit, added two other examples.

Comment: Is this the idea? I am at a cell with 5 units of energy. I can move to any adjacent cell, if the cell I move to has value 2 then 2 of my units of energy are absorbed and I have 3 units of energy. I can move as long as I have 1 or more units of energy and the cell I want to move into has a value less than or equal to the units of energy I have remaining. When my energy reaches 0 I have to wait for some event while my energy recharges or I am just stopped. The question is for any given cell which other cells can I reach with a set amount of energy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want to do is a basic kind of search, where on each iteration you check the surrounding squares. I've come up with a mockup example [with this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9S7Qe/). Open the console, click run, and it should print out the example map and the places it can get to in 3 steps from (2, 2).

There's some extra code in there for setup, but the main code is the `search_rec` function:

```
function search_rec(
      map, // The input 'difficulty' map
      output, // The output map (puts '1's in spots that can be reached)
              // Should be the same size as the input map
      x, y, // The current/starting position
      limit) { // The number of spaces you are allowed to move

    // If the number of spaces allowed to move is negative, then we can't
    // reach this position, so we stop
    if (limit < 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, if the limit is >= 0, then we can make it here and we
    // store that in the output
    output[y][x] = 1;

    // Now, for each of the four directions
    // Check if we're at a map boundary
    if (x > 0) {
        // If we're not, then we recurse, moving our starting point in
        // the given direction, and lowering our limit by 1 (for the
        // base movement) as well as the 'difficulty' of the terrain of
        // the space we're moving into

        search_rec(map, output, x - 1, y,
        //                      ^ change position
                      limit           - 1          - map[y][x - 1]);
        //   lower limit ^ by the base ^ and the difficulty ^
    }
    if (x < map[0].length - 1) {
        search_rec(map, output, x + 1, y, limit - map[y][x + 1] - 1);
    }
    if (y > 0) {
        search_rec(map, output, x, y - 1, limit - map[y - 1][x] - 1);
    }
    if (y < map.length - 1) {
        search_rec(map, output, x, y + 1, limit - map[y + 1][x] - 1);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that logic makes sense, and it's actually solving the problem you wanted solved.

Comment: You're an absolute genius.  My great lament is only that I can only offer you one upvote and a checkmark.  If this were reddit, I would give you gold.